# Load balancing between two discovery servers

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I am running discovery in peer to peer mode where I have 2 discovery servers, The servers both are exchanging information and represent the current set of discovered services.

In the serviceUrls that services use to connect to eureka there is a csv list where discoveryserver1,discoveryserver2 is present.

So the services are always going to discoveryserver1 unless there isa failure then they go to discoveryserver2.

What I would like to do is have the discovery clients round robin between discoveryserver1 and discoveryserver2 so that the load on the services are equally balanced. Rather that one discovery server will is heavily loaded and the other which is not used (much)

I can't see a way to do this unless I rewrite the discovery client.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to use edge server as zuul ( luckily available in spring cloud stack :) ). So all your requests go through zuul proxy which uses ribbon as a loadbalancer for your mid-tier services. Ofcourse it is important to have redundant zuul servers so you will have to set up some LB on front as BigIp or other anyway.

OR

if you are using eureka without zuul and the only client is code you own, then you can either:

1. annotate it with LoadBalancerClient or
2. use RestTemplate or
3. use FeignClient or
4. other options I dont know ; )

+add ribbon on classpath and you are good to go.

Comment: I use zuul as a gateway server and it is in a redundant configuration to get incoming requests served to the various many micro services.  I suppose I could add the @EnableZuulProxy to each service and put a rule for the eureka endpoints although since eureka is not a normal service in that sense I can;t use it exactly in a normal route.  I suppose a static route but I will have to explore.

Comment: This is mostly concerned with the underlying spring cloud discovery client that is built into the all when you include @EnableDiscoveryClient

Comment: On reading the docs for zuul using the zuul.routes.xxx.uri, the uri formulation is not load balanced via ribbon, so that won't work